# Real time video capture?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, video

Just as a hobby, I want to capture realtime video. The source of video for a start would be a web camera. I have one from logitech. What I am trying to do is make a custom window with Real time video display as one part and other miscellaneous widgets. As a starting point I looked in Qt and phonon did sound promising. But installing it on linux is a PIA. Googled it and found no alternative, just theortical stuff is given and no practical example or direction. In VLC player I just selected some options and voila, web camera started giving line feed. How can I start for something of this sort. Also the jargon of video capture like codecs etc has always been confusing for me. Can someone with expertise in this area guide me and other members regarding the basics of video capture programming (real time/stream/reading from a file). And why there are hundreds of codecs, why can't we have a single standard one?????????.

The whole business of video display is very very confusing to me, variety of backends, variety of codecs etc. Ohh!! the most important thing I want to do it on LINUX machine. I am using C++/Qt/RHEL 4. Language(C,C++,Java) is no barrier, but I want to develop only on a linux platform.

Thanks

Comment: The (main) reason there are hundreds of codecs is because half of them are proprietary, and noone wants to pay royalties.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to be using [Video4Linux](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). It's probably one of the easiest way of dealing with video in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Qt, Phonon is **the** Choice.

RHEL 4 is too old for phonon. If you use a newer distro, phonon are much easier.